# Is there any shorter way for this

Tags: javascript, json

I have written the following code snippet to produce an object.

```
{
    "2018": {
        "02": {
            "18": {
                "scheduledSlots": 0,
                "totalSlots": 0,
                "slots": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This feels just wrong way

```
   const obj = {}
        obj[date[2]] = {};
        obj[date[2]][date[1]] = {};
        obj[date[2]][date[1]][date[0]] = {};
        const day = obj[date[2]][date[1]][date[0]];
        day.scheduledSlots = 0;
        day.totalSlots = 0;
        day.slots = null;
```

I just need to know if there is a better way to approach this

This is a hash map.
It will need to add another day to it.

```
{
    "2018": {
        "02": {
            "18": {
                "scheduledSlots": 0,
                "totalSlots": 0,
                "slots": null
            }
        }
        "03": {
            "12": {
                "scheduledSlots": 0,
                "totalSlots": 0,
                "slots": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are having a *that complex* structure of data?

Comment: @RomeoSierra its a hash map for populating a calendar

Comment: You could maybe make a function for initializing object

Comment: @boyman how does that reduce the line of code

Comment: Still, having a key like "2018:02:18" is better isn't it? I mean, just imagine you traversing this data structure!

Comment: @RomeoSierra i have edited the question to give more context on the problem

Comment: I get your point @ShubhamBhardwaj. Problem I see is that, you have made this overly complex. Decoding a key of `"2018:02:18"` into whatever that you want is way less complicated programmatically than trying to traverse such a complex structure. You can achieve your goal with a much flatter data structure.

Answer (score 3):

If you create entire object at once you may want to use the [literal notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer):

```
const obj = {
    [date[2]]: {
        [date[1]]: {
            [date[0]]: {
                scheduledSlots: 0,
                totalSlots: 0,
                slots: null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you later need an acces to the `const day`:

```
const day = {
    scheduledSlots: 0,
    totalSlots: 0,
    slots: null
}
const obj = {
    [date[2]]: {
        [date[1]]: {
            [date[0]]: day
        }
    }
}
```

@EDIT If you need to iterate then this should do the job:

```
Object.prototype._next = function(name)
{
    if(!this[name]) this[name] = {};
    return this[name];
}

const obj = {}
const day = obj._next(date[2])._next(date[1])._next(date[0]) = {
    scheduledSlots: 0,
    totalSlots: 0,
    slots: null
}
```

Comment: this would not work when i have to add a new date to the hash map, the prev state will be overwritten

Comment: @ShubhamBhardwaj Totally forgot about it. Edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combined approach by giving the path to the property of the values.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var last = path.pop();

    path.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object)[last] = value;
}

var object = {},
    date = '18-02-2018'.split('-').reverse();

setValue(object, [... date, 'scheduledSlots'], 0);
setValue(object, [... date, 'totalSlots'], 0);
setValue(object, [... date, 'slots'], null);

console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```